# Does chrome intentionally prevent css :hover thrashing

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, pointer-events

For example in Chromium 58.0.3029.81, the following will stop flashing between selectable and not selectable state if you mess around with it for some time by dragging a text selection around (it might take a minute). After that it seems to always stay in `pointer-events: none` state until reload, even if tab is switched.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKeaRm

```
.avoid-clicks:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

No such timeout appears to happen in firefox for instance.

My question if this is intentional or a silent error.

Comment: Possibly related, but not exactly the same, is a throttling of mouse events while scrolling. https://blog.chromium.org/2015/07/chrome-45-beta-new-es2015-features.html https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/blink-dev/KIoVljZw5fc

Comment: @JoshLee I am kinda sceptical, since as it says in the second link, other browsers have had this behavior even longer... But scrolling or resizing does cause it to "break" within seconds rather than over a minute!